# Can you propagate comfrey by stems?

Tags: propagation, cuttings, comfrey

I'm wanting to get a lot of comfrey this year, and am wondering if anyone has had good success from propagating it by stem cuttings.

Comment: The Royal Horticultural Society website says take root cuttings in winter. That will give you as many plants as you want till you get bored chopping up the roots into 3 inch lengths, but you missed the boat for this year unless your climate has a very late spring.

Comment: i know about root cuttings, and you can do it in the spring/summer also

Answer (score 0):

I cut the stem that flowered and planted it but it's been several weeks and not sure it's rooted but it's still alive.  A few have rotted away.  Planted around the end of February/Early March in SW Florida.  Not sure if they will eventually root and start creating new leaves.  Maybe in a month I will see progress but so far no change.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Please note that this site does not work like  forum. This would be an answer once you succeed.